# How much weight can a 2x4 bear horizontally?

Tags: studs

I am building an indoor climbing wall that will have 4 or 5 different sections no longer than 44". I am planning on using 2x4 to make frames for each of the sections that will be 96" by up to 44". The studs will be 16" apart. I am wondering if 2x4s will be sufficient or if I need to be doing 2x6s.  The sections of the wall will all be overhung and not vertical.

Comment: It's really not clear what your design is or how this thing will be installed and used. Please update with sketches or more detailed descriptions.

Comment: Given the use you should employ or consult a professional engineer.

Comment: @SteveWellens: given that it's a roof section, we can probably assume not much weight...